# SQL recursive querying using array with numeric type

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, casting, common-table-expression

I try to run a recursive query to get shortest paths where the id should occure once in a path at most.
The view I am using looks like:

```
pkp_symmetric(
    personknows numeric(20,0),
    personisknown numeric(20,0),
    creation timestamp)
```

When running

```
with recursive temp(persStart, persNext, pfad, tiefe, pcycle ) 
            as 
            (select pkp.personknows, pkp.personIsKnown, array[pkp.personKnows], 1, false 
            from pkp_symmetric pkp--pidstart, pidstart, pidstart
            union all 
            select p.personknows, p.personisknown, t.pfad|| t.persNext, t.tiefe + 1, p.personknows = ANY(t.pfad)  
            from pkp_symmetric p join  temp t 
            on p.personknows = t.persNext where not pcycle )

            select * from temp t
```

I get the following error:

```
SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: recursive query "temp" column 3 has type numeric(20,0)[] in non-recursive term but type numeric[] overall
  Hinweis: Cast the output of the non-recursive term to the correct type.
  Position: 119
  SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: recursive query "temp" column 3 has type numeric(20,0)[] in non-recursive term but type numeric[] overall
  Hinweis: Cast the output of the non-recursive term to the correct type.
  Position: 119
    SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: recursive query "temp" column 3 has type numeric(20,0)[] in non-recursive term but type numeric[] overall
  Hinweis: Cast the output of the non-recursive term to the correct type.
  Position: 119
      SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: recursive query "temp" column 3 has type numeric(20,0)[] in non-recursive term but type numeric[] overall
  Hinweis: Cast the output of the non-recursive term to the correct type.
  Position: 119
        ERROR: recursive query "temp" column 3 has type numeric(20,0)[] in non-recursive term but type numeric[] overall
  Hinweis: Cast the output of the non-recursive term to the correct type.
  Position: 119
        ERROR: recursive query "temp" column 3 has type numeric(20,0)[] in non-recursive term but type numeric[] overall
  Hinweis: Cast the output of the non-recursive term to the correct type.
  Position: 119
```

I would appreciate to get some help.
Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dealing with bounded data types in arrays is a bit tricky. It seems the only way to get this to work is a clumsy:

```
select pkp.personknows, pkp.personisknown, array[]::numeric[] || pkp.personknows
...
```

in the non-recursive part.

I have no idea why array[personknows]::numeric[] doesn't achieve the same thing.

Comment: I tried, but this does not work for me. I still get the same error.